# How to add shadows to a ShaderMaterial in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm using a custom shader to add a gradient color to a model, but the shader lacks definition in terms of shadows not showing the edges more clearly (see first image). It's like it has a "glowing" effect.

I'd like to have the custom shader display it's edges clearly as the second image does.

How can I achieve this?

`THREE.ShaderMaterial`:

[image]

`THREE.MeshStandardMaterial`:

[image]

Custom shader with gradient:

```
const mat: THREE.Material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
uniforms: {
    color1: {
        value: new THREE.Color("#01e2f6")
    },
    color2: {
        value: new THREE.Color("#FF6969")
    },
    color3: {
        value: new THREE.Color("#FFF9DE")
    },
    bMin: {
        value: this.mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min
    },
    bMax: {
        value: this.mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max
    }
},
vertexShader: `
    uniform vec3 bMin;
    uniform vec3 bMax;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
    vUv.y = (position.y - bMin.y) / (bMax.y - bMin.y);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
    `,
fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec3 color1;
    uniform vec3 color2;
    uniform vec3 color3;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {              
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color1, color2, vUv.y), 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, vec4(mix(color2, color3, vUv.y), 1.0), vUv.y);
    }
    `
});

this.mesh.material = mat;
```

Comment: I would modify `MeshStandardMaterial` with `.onBeforeCompile`, instead of the using of `ShaderMaterial`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `MeshStandardMaterial` and `.onBeforeCompile`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/addons/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';
console.clear();

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color("white");
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2));

const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene( new RoomEnvironment(), 0.04 ).texture;

let cntr = new THREE.Vector2();
let teethCount = 18;
let teethStep = -(Math.PI * 2) / teethCount;
let rMin = 4;
let rMax = 5;
let rHole = 1.5;
let holePts = [];
let basePts = [
  new THREE.Vector2(0, rMax).rotateAround(cntr, (teethStep / 4) * 1),
  new THREE.Vector2(0, rMax).rotateAround(cntr, (teethStep / 4) * 2),
  new THREE.Vector2(0, rMin).rotateAround(cntr, (teethStep / 4) * 3),
  new THREE.Vector2(0, rMin).rotateAround(cntr, (teethStep / 4) * 4)
];

let shapePts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < teethCount; i++) {
  basePts.forEach((p) => {
    shapePts.push(p.clone().rotateAround(cntr, teethStep * i));
    holePts.push(p.clone().setLength(rHole).rotateAround(cntr, teethStep * i));
  });
}
holePts.reverse();

let gearShape = new THREE.Shape(shapePts);
gearShape.holes.push(new THREE.Path(holePts));
let g = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(gearShape, {
  steps: 1,
  depth: 1.5,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelSegments: 3,
  bevelSize: 0.1,
  bevelThickness: 0.1
}).translate(0, 0, -0.5).rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromBufferAttribute(g.attributes.position);

let m = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
  metalness: 0.9,
  roughness: 0.5,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.uniforms.height = m.userData.uniforms.height;
    shader.uniforms.color1 = m.userData.uniforms.colors.color1;
    shader.uniforms.color2 = m.userData.uniforms.colors.color2;
    shader.uniforms.color3 = m.userData.uniforms.colors.color3;
    shader.vertexShader = `
      uniform vec2 height;
      varying float hRatio;
      ${shader.vertexShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <begin_vertex>`,
      `#include <begin_vertex>
        hRatio = 1. - ((position.y - height.x) / (height.y - height.x));
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
    shader.fragmentShader = `
      uniform vec3 color1;
      uniform vec3 color2;
      uniform vec3 color3;
      varying float hRatio;
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <color_fragment>`,
      `#include <color_fragment>
        vec3 col1 = mix(color1, color2, hRatio);
        vec3 col2 = mix(color2, color3, hRatio);
        diffuseColor.rgb = mix(col1, col2, hRatio);
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  }
});
m.userData = {
  uniforms: {
    height: {value: new THREE.Vector2(box.min.y, box.max.y)}, // min, max
    colors: {
      color1: {
          value: new THREE.Color("#01e2f6")
      },
      color2: {
          value: new THREE.Color("#FF6969")
      },
      color3: {
          value: new THREE.Color("#FFF9DE")
      }
    }
  }
}
let gear = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(gear);

let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(
  new THREE.EdgesGeometry(g),
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x404040 })
);
gear.add(lines);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```

PS The gear is from here: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/zYaZPPw